# Sharing a page with addthis and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, facebook

I have a page that contains a gallery of images that can be opened with *fancybox*. Each image can be shared to facebook with *addthis* and this works fine.

The problem is that I want to change the return url that is shared, so when the image is clicked in facebook the user is taken to the gallery and not the image. Can this be done? I have made a working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/qewymf44/5/).

html

```
       <h2>Share this page, not just the image</h2>

        <a title="test for sharing" 
class="fancybox" "href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg ">
<img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg " title="test"/></a>
```

jQuery

```
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      beforeShow: function() {
        this.title = '<div class="addthis addthis_default_style ">
<a href="' + this.href + '" addthis:url="' + this.href + '" addthis:title="' + this.title + '" class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a></div>';
      },
      afterShow: function() {
        addthis.toolbox(
          $(".addthis").get()
        );
      },
      helpers: {
        title: {
          type: 'inside'
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Only if you don’t share the image URL directly, but the URL of an HTML document that has the image set as thumbnail. Then you can redirect human visitors easily using JavaScript. (Or via a server-side redirect, but then you have to add an exception for the Facebook scraper.)

Comment: Well I sure would be interested to know how to do that. I've tried for ages and the only parameters that facebook sees are the image url. Any pointers you could give me? Thanks

Comment: _“and the only parameters that facebook sees are the image url”_ - well that’s because that’s what you are passing to it ... `this.href` is the href attribute of your link, and that is the image URL. Since to keep the fancybox working the way it is, you can probably not just switch that out for the URL of an HTML document - so I’d suggest you place that document URL into an additional attribute on the link, such as `data-shareurl`, and then access that in your code where currently `this.href` is used ..

Comment: Thanks for this. I've tried using the existing title variable to pass the url (google for fun in this case) but no luck. Facebook still thinks the return url is the image url. I've made a fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/jmdzvLab/1/

Comment: You're still assigning `this.href` as the URL to share, and that's still the image URL. And `www.google.com` is a relative URL, you need to use an absolute one including the protocol.

Comment: Thanks. I follow you, I'm not just quite sure how to do this.

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle with an adjusted url but still does not work. Driving me crazy...http://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/jmdzvLab/3/